# Output form keys and values to YAML

Tags: php, yaml

I'm trying to output the form elements and values entered by the user to a YAML file. I'm using Spyc to parse and dump the code, but I'm not married to that if there's another way. Here's what I have so far:

```
include('Spyc.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $file = "data.yaml";
  $yaml = Spyc::YAMLLoad($_POST);
  $yaml_out = Spyc::YAMLDump($yaml);
  file_put_contents($file, $yaml_out, FILE_APPEND);
  header('Location: thanks.php'); 
}
```

When I run the page, all I get is:

```
---
```

which is the opening syntax for YAML, but no actual data. Am I getting the $_POST array incorrectly?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Best - Joe

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Didn't need the load command at all.

```
include('Spyc.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $file = "data.yaml";
 unset($_POST['submit']);
 $yaml = Spyc::YAMLDump($_POST);
 file_put_contents($file, $yaml, FILE_APPEND);
 header('Location: thanks.php'); 
}
```